# Prove that n! is not in O(n^p) for any constant natural number p

Tags: math, proof, proofs

How can I prove that n! is not in O(n^p) for any constant natural number p?
And is (n k)(n choose k) in O(n^p), for all k?

Comment: @Mitch: If you made that an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Tony: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 10):

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says that

```
log (n!) = n log n - n + O(log n) = O(n log n)
```

But

```
log (n^p) = p log n = O(log n)
```

for constant `p`. Clearly `n!` grows faster than `n^p` and hence it is not `O(n^p)`.

Comment: You could also note without using stirlings approximation that log(n!)=log(n)+log(n-1)+...+log(2)+log(1). log(1)=0, so every other term has to be _at least_ log(2) or larger. That gives log(n!) > n*log(2), which of course means it's O(n). As you noted it's actually O(n*log n), but O(log n) also grows way faster than O(log n).

Comment: +1. I was attempting not to do the homework for them ;). but I probably should have hinted at Stirling's factorial approximation.

Answer (score 8):

You can prove that n! is not in O(n^p) for any constant natural number p, by showing that you can always choose n (for a fixed constant p), so that `n! > n^p`.

(to get an idea, pick a few low values of p and plot n! against n^p)

The reasoning for the second part follows the same lines. Bound (n choose k) and then use first part.

Hint: as Casablanca noted, you can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: To be precise, *for all* n > n0, where n0 is some positive integer. You can't choose a single value n. Counterexample: p=10, n=2. 2^10 > 2!.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should revise that comment. To *disprove* n! = O(n^p): given p, then for *any* n0 > 0, there exists a (single) value n > n0 such that n! > n^p.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit (3/2011) - easier method using only simple calculus**

One way to show O(n!) does not equal O(n^p) is to compare the log of n! with the log of n^p.

ln(n!) = sum(ln(i)) {i: 1 to n}

ln(n^p) = p*ln(n)

That doesn't seem to help since we don't know what the sum of the logs would be.  The trick is to calculate a lower bound by using the integral of ln(i)di from 1 to n

This can be seen in the image below that the ln(x) in black is less than the sum step function in blue.

[image]

Given that the indefinite integral of ln(i)di is i*ln(i) - i + C, we can integrate from 1 to n to get:

n*ln(n) - n + 1 as the lower bound.

And because no p can be chosen that is larger than all possible n:

O(p*ln(n)) < O(n*ln(n)), O(n^p) < O(n!)

note: integrating ln(n) to get an approximation to ln(n!) is the basis for Stirling's approximation.  This is a rougher approximation and if you continue it by taking the anti-log: n! >= e*(n/e)^n, whereas Stirling's has sqrt(2*pi*n) instead of e.

Integrating from 1 to n+1 would give you an upper bound (the sum step function would fit inside the graph of ln(n))